# Problem in installing my android application

Tags: android

I developed one android application and tested it in HTC desire (sdk 2.2), i can install it and i can work on it. But when i try to install it in lower android sdk devices like HTC EVO (SDK 2.1) or Sony xperia (sdk 1.6) it displaying "Parser Error". And in the manifest file i set the the following code.

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" android:maxSdkVersion="8"/>
```

I dont know what is the solution for this anybody please help me if you know the answer.

Thanks and Regards,
Rajapandian.K

Comment: Can you post your logcat Messages?, What Message you had yield in your Logcat?

Comment: @Sankar Ganesh, I am not installing the app by connecting it to the system. I installed it through my gmail, I do not know how to get the log cat message when installing the app through gmail account.

Answer (score 0):

This error doesn't look like something related to the manifest, probably a function which has changed between versions. Look into logCat to see the stack trace of the error, and you'll probably be able to know a little more about your error.